# Airtightness of a plastic-on-rubber seal

Tags: material-science, gas

I want to make a pressure container out of this food container
[image: Text]
The seal is rubber that is pushed into plastic edges.
However, I don't know if it's going to work until after i've attached an air valve to it.
My question is - at what rate is it going to pass air at an inside pressure of 2 atmospheres?
I wan't it to hold at at least above 1.7 atmospheres over the course of two days. Thanks!

Comment: Well, it isn’t really made to keep pressure in, so hard to say. As an aside, I would question the pressure safety without a more positive hold down mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us start with the force the pressure will exert on the lid. Assuming you mean 1.7 atmospheres above the external air pressure, at approximately 14.7 psi atmospheric pressure times 1.7 will equal a pressure of 24.99 pounds on each square inch of the lid. You can figure the area of the lid and multiply it by 24.99 to find the total pressure exerted on the lid. For instance a 4 inch by 6 inch lid will have an area of 24 square inches, 24 times 24.99 will exert a total of 599.76 pounds pressure on the lid. If the lid hold downs are strong enough to keep the lid on and the rubber seal compressed enough to not leak then you will be ok. I hope I have understood your question correctly.